# How to use list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, list

How do I use list comprehension for doing this:

```
MCs= [['foo', 180.9], ['bar', 163.5], ['noo', 140.3]]
```

Want

```
[['foo'], ['bar'], ['noo']]
```

using

`MCs =  [list(x[0]) for x in MCs`]

I get this:

```
  [['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r'], ['n', 'o', 'o']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need this:

```
MCs = [[x[0]] for x in MCs]
```

Strings are iterable, and `list(iterable)` returns a list of elements yielded by the argument (i.e. characters, in this case).

Answer (score 5):

That's because `x[0]` is e.g. `'foo'` and `list` turns an iterable into a list containing the items of the iterable - iterating a string yields its characters one at a time. It's unrelated to the list comprehension, the same thing would happen if you used `list('foo')`. To make a singleton list, just wrap the expression in square brackes, i.e. `[[mc[0]] for mc in mcs]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
[[x[0]] for x in MCs]
```

`list(c)` takes a collection of *something* and makes it into a list. A string is a collection of characters, so that's what you get, a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

To get precisely what you ask for do this:

```
>>> [[x[0]] for x in MCs]
[['foo'], ['bar'], ['noo']]
```

But perhaps what you really want is this:

```
>>> [x[0] for x in MCs]
['foo', 'bar', 'noo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your answer.

```
[[x[0],] for x in MCs]
```

So dissecting what your list comprehension:

```
for x in  [['foo', 180.9], ['bar', 163.5], ['noo', 140.3]]:
# x = ['foo', 180.9] first time through
# x[0] = 'foo'
# list(x[0]) = ['f','o','o']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using zip:

```
[[x] for x in zip(*MCs)[0]]
```